# git merge creates several ~HEAD files. Unable to merge

Tags: git

trying to perform a simple git merge in vscode, but when I do it tells me there are merge conflicts. I check the git tab and find this:

[image]

I've never seen this before. When I try to click on any of the files under "MERGE CHANGES", a popup on the right informs me that the file is not found.

Any ideas why I am getting this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first have seen messages like this one:

```
        output(opt, 1, _("Error: Refusing to lose untracked file at %s; "
                         "writing to %s instead."),
```

or these:

```
        if (!old_path) {
                output(opt, 1, _("CONFLICT (%s/delete): %s deleted in %s "
                       "and %s in %s. Version %s of %s left in tree at %s."),
                       change, path, delete_branch, change_past,
                       change_branch, change_branch, path, alt_path);
        } else {
                output(opt, 1, _("CONFLICT (%s/delete): %s deleted in %s "
                       "and %s to %s in %s. Version %s of %s left in tree at %s."),
                       change, old_path, delete_branch, change_past, path,      
                       change_branch, change_branch, path, alt_path);
        }
```

or one of several others along the same lines.  It's possible that whatever front end you're using to insulate yourself from command-line Git is eating these messages, which is a terrible disservice as they're quite critical to completing the merge manually.

Basically, they mean that something has gone wrong with the *automated* merge process, and you must now complete the merge by hand.  These instructions—the ones you apparently never saw—contain the specific information about *what* went wrong, to help you out in your task.

The extra files are those that Git was not able to merge on its own.  You should use them to construct the correct merge result.